# Using SQL to parse through logs and grab referrer at first page view

Tags: sql, sql-server, logparser

I have a log file I am parsing through and finding an application id from a specific page. I can grab that and their IP fine, but I would like to take that IP, find the earliest point they connect to the site and look at their referrer there. I'm running into trouble how to pull that info. This here gets me their Application ID, if they're on mobile, if they're a new applicant, if they're using the Spanish version of our site, and their IP. Is there anyway to tag that IP, look back at the earliest time (the long is all on the same day, so just need normal hh:mm:ss) and then grab the referrer from that line all in one statement? Or will I have to do this query, then do another query for each IP?

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(
        TO_INT(REPLACE_CHR(EXTRACT_TOKEN(TO_LOWERCASE(cs-uri-query),3,'+'),';','')),
        TO_INT(REPLACE_CHR(EXTRACT_TOKEN(TO_LOWERCASE(cs-uri-query),2,'+'),';',''))
    ) AS ApplicationID,
    CASE 
        COALESCE(
            INDEX_OF(cs(User-Agent), 'iPhone'),
            INDEX_OF(cs(User-Agent), 'iPad'),
            INDEX_OF(cs(User-Agent), 'Android'),
            INDEX_OF(cs(User-Agent), 'BlackBerry'),
            INDEX_OF(cs(User-Agent), 'Windows Phone')
        ) WHEN NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS Mobile,
    CASE TO_LOWERCASE(SUBSTR(EXTRACT_FILENAME(cs(Referer)),0,INDEX_OF(EXTRACT_FILENAME(cs(Referer)),'?')))
        WHEN 'application.aspx' THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS NewApplication,
    CASE TO_LOWERCASE(EXTRACT_TOKEN(cs(Referer),5,'/')) WHEN 'es' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS Spanish,
        EXTRACT_FILENAME(c-ip)
     AS IP,

INTO %outPutFile%
FROM %logFile%
WHERE %whereClause%
    AND TO_LOWERCASE(EXTRACT_FILENAME(cs-uri-stem)) 
        IN ('logclientconfirmation')
    AND TO_UPPERCASE(cs-method) = 'POST'
    AND TO_LOWERCASE(cs-uri-query) LIKE '{application}%'
ORDER BY ApplicationID
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Log Parser 2.2 to sort through the logs. So I think it's all in Transact-SQL syntax. (I think that's what you're asking.)

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way you can do all of this with a single query; the SQL of LogParser is not a standard SQL implementation and, for example, it doesn't support JOINs, which would be very helpful here.

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, I've kinda figured it out and got it all working together between two SQL statements.